# How to remove an ItemOverlay on touch and add another on touch?

Tags: android

This is MapOverlay:

```
class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
{
    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, 
    boolean shadow, long when) 
    {

            return true;

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) 
    {   
        //---when user lifts his finger---
        if (event.getAction() == 1) {                
            GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
                (int) event.getX(),
                (int) event.getY());


            List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.splash_logo);
            ItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new ItemizedOverlay(drawable, getApplicationContext());

            OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(p, "I'm in LA!");
            itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);

            mapView.invalidate();

            Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(
                getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
                    p.getLatitudeE6()  / 1E6, 
                    p.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);

                 String add = "";
                if (addresses.size() > 0) 
                {
                    for (int i=0; i<addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); 
                         i++)
                       add += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
                }

                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), add, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                addr = add;
            }
            catch (IOException e) {                
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   

            return true;
        }
        else                
            return false;
    }        
}
```

This is ItemizedOverlay:

```
class ItemizedOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>{


    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    private Context mContext;

    public ItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
     super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public ItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
      super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
      mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
      return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
      return mOverlays.size();
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    public void removeOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mOverlays.remove(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    public void clear() {
        mOverlays.clear();
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
      OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
      AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
      dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
      dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
      dialog.show();
      return true;
    }

}
```

I'm able to add more than one item overlay with this but not able to call clear so that as to remove the itemziedoverylay item.

What I want to do is this: When I touch on a particular point of the map, the previous itemized overlays should be deleted and a new one at that point should be created. I know I've to call clear() but not able to figure out where exactly should I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you have to write this code in your mapoverlay Class

`if (itemizedoverlay != null) { 
itemizedoverlay.overlayClear();
}`

Comment: through this code i want to tell that the method which you have made in the class ItemizedOverlay named clear () you have to call that in youur previous class so then and then only it will clear